# Spark RDD from a sequencefile and deserialization

Tags: apache-spark, deserialization, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.0 and I want to read a sqeuence file -- key is filename (ext) and value is actually a list of java objects of type Myclass

Here is my code for doing that without Spark.

```
val ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/seqfile"))
val data = ois.readObject.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[MyClass]]
val scalalist = data.asScala
```

I want to use Spark to do the same, However I am not sure when the serialized data is available in string, how do I create an RDD where the 2nd element of the tuple is casted to List of MyClass objects.

```
val seq_rdd = sc.sequenceFile("/path/to/seqfile", classOf[Text], classOf[BytesWritable])
val seq_formatted_rdd = seq_rdd.map { case (text, bytes) => (text.toString, bytes.copyBytes) }
val my_rdd = seq_formatted_rdd.map { case (text, ser_bytes) => (text, new ByteArrayInputStream(ser_bytes)) }
```

I get the following exception because ByteArrayInputStream does not implement Serializable:

> - object not serializable (class: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream, value: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@73d5a077)

After that, I want to do the following:

```
val my_rdd1 = my_rdd.map { case (text, bytestream) => (text, new ObjectInputStream(bytestream).readObject.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[MyClass]])}
```

Comment: Do you need to read only one file? If so, you can just read it as you did and then use `SparkContext#parallelize` to create an RDD.  

There's no meaning in all that maps, unless you need to read several files.

Comment: The sequence contains many (few thousand) serialized files as values. Each of those values is of type java.util.List[MyClass].